# Using a counter in bubble sort

Tags: java, methods, counter, bubble-sort

The problem is to count how many times my bubble sort algorithm switches the places of numbers. I tried to use a variable which increments by one each time, but I think there may be an error with scopes or something similar. Instead of returning a number such as 6 (which means numbers were swapped 6 times), it returns 0, which is what I initialized my variable as. How would I get my program to work?

```
public static int sort(int arr[]) {
    int length = arr.length;
    int temp;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (length); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (length); j++) {
            if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
                temp = arr[j-1];
                arr[j-1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Your counter seems to be well-placed. Why do you think there is an error ? What result did you get and what result do you think you should have got ?

Comment: I just get 0, which is what I initialize the variable as (line 4). I would like it it count up by 1 every time the if statement on line 7 runs

Comment: @KenzoEngineer It seems your array contains only one element or all the elements are same.

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik I used a test case with many different integers and the sort works properly so that would not be the case

Comment: Can you post a test case with an expected value for the counter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your algorithm is not optimized because of your for loop condition and initialization. As a result you are comparing an element with itself which is redundant.

Proper approach should be like below:

```
int yourCounter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
 for (int j = 1; j < length-i; j++)
   if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
     //swap code
     //yourCounter++;
   }
```

your counter should give you proper result then.

Comment: I changed my code to look like your yet yourCounter still shows up as 0 when I return it...

Comment: @KenzoEngineer with this call `System.out.println(sort(new int[]
      { 1, 5, 2, 6, 4 }));` I'm getting output as `3` which is correct.